# How can I set the scrolling position of a GridView in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, layout, android-actionbar

I am using a gridview in my android app. Now, for certain reasons, I am using a self build "fake" ActionBar, that is composed of a simple LinearLayout at the top of my layout.

Now, want I want to achieve is a similiar effect as in the app [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) . The gridview should initially start below the aciton bar and flow behind it as you scroll down in the gridview.

The actual question is, how can I position the gridview below my action bar (the LinearLayout) and still let it flow behind it?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fake_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color" >

    // Here normally would be more stuff for the action bar (text, buttons, etc.)

</LinearLayout>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
</GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to use a fake `ActionBar`. Lucky you, there was actually a post on the Android Developers Google+ page not too long ago about this exact topic.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/T4FQkkJ5bGc

Comment: And this is why you should never post just a link as an answer without the relevant content quoted. The link no longer works and the content is forever lost.